# HighCharts - How can I split data labels in Sankey diagram?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

It's my first time working with HighCharts and I want to do a Sankey diagram. In my data labels I want to display an array containing three items and I want to show each one of those items in a separate box. How can I separate them? As you can see [here](https://ibb.co/b1hhYR), first mapping, all three items are displayed in one single box now.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/morn2e4g/3/)
My code:

```
var chart= Highcharts.chart('container', {
title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
},

series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
    data: [
        [['item1','item2', 'item3'], 'res', 5 ],
        ['Brazil', 'France', 1 ],
        ['Brazil', 'Spain', 1 ],
        ['Brazil', 'England', 1 ],
        ['Canada', 'Portugal', 1 ],
        ['Canada', 'France', 5 ],
        ['Canada', 'England', 1 ],
        ['Mexico', 'Portugal', 1 ],
        ['Mexico', 'France', 1 ],
        ['Mexico', 'Spain', 5 ],
        ['Mexico', 'England', 1 ],
        ['USA', 'Portugal', 1 ],
        ['USA', 'France', 1 ],
        ['USA', 'Spain', 1 ],
        ['USA', 'England', 5 ]         
    ],
     dataLabels: {

         borderWidth: 1,
         backgroundColor: 'rgb(224, 236, 255)',
         borderRadius: 5,
         style: {           
            fontSize: '1em'
        }
    },
    useHTML:'true',
    type: 'sankey',
    name: 'Sankey demo series'
}]

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i correctly got your question - then you should use nodeFormatter in plotOptions.sankey.dataLabels config and set useHTML to true. Just take value and create separate divs for each of values (in your example).

```
plotOptions: {
    sankey: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            useHTML: true,
            nodeFormatter: function(point) {
            console.log(this, point);
            if (Array.isArray(this.key)) {
                return '<div>'+this.key.join('</div><div>')+'</div>';
            }
                return this.key;
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Here is [plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/w9pzhug6/)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!